# Hybris WCMS Error -- Invald CMSSite type

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm in the process of installing hybris6.0 on my local and I've successfully installed, build and started hybrisserver and when I go to to my WCMS Cockpit I get a HTTP 500 Error stating 'type code 'CMSSite' invalid'. I have also updated my host file to have hybris.localhost point to 127.0.0.1.

Below is my localextensions.xml file from my config folder:

```
    <path dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}" />



    <!--COMMON EXTENSIONS-->
    <extension name="acceleratorcms" />
    <extension name="acceleratorfacades" />
    <extension name="acceleratorservices" />
    <extension name="acceleratorstorefrontcommons" />
    <extension name="basecommerce" />
    <extension name="btg" />
    <extension name="cms2" />
    <extension name="cms2lib" />
    <extension name="commercefacades" />
    <extension name="commerceservices" />
    <extension name="customerreview" />
    <extension name="hmc" />
    <extension name="ldap" />
    <extension name="payment" />
    <extension name="platformhmc" />
    <extension name="promotions" />
    <extension name="solrfacetsearch" />
    <extension name="solrfacetsearchhmc" />
    <extension name="ticketsystem" />
    <extension name="voucher" />
    <!--REQUIRED extensions not listed-->
    <extension name="platformbackoffice" />
    <extension name="springintegrationlibs" />


    <!--ADDITIONAL EXTENSIONS-->
    <extension name="cockpit" />
    <extension name="admincockpit" />
    <extension name="cmscockpit" />
    <extension name="b2badmincockpit" />
    <extension name="btgcockpit" />
    <extension name="productcockpit" />
    <extension name="importcockpit" />
    <extension name="mcc" />
    <extension name="classificationsystems" />
    <extension name="classificationsystemshmc" />
    <extension name="commercesearch" />
    <extension name="commercesearchhmc" />
    <extension name="backoffice" />
    <!--<extension name="ordermanagementbackoffice" />--> <!-- THIS EXTENSION IS MISSING -->
    <extension name="commercesearchbackoffice" />
    <extension name="addonsupport" />
    <extension name="solrserver" />

    <!-- ADDONS -->
    <!--<extension name="assistedservicesstorefront" />--> <!-- THIS EXTENSION IS MISSING -->
    <!--<extension name="configureablebundleservices" />--> <!-- THIS EXTENSION IS MISSING -->

    <!--TEST-->
    <extension name="cscockpit" />
    <extension name="reportcockpit" />



    <!-- ext-template -->
    <extension name="yempty" />
    <extension name="yhacext" />
    <extension name="yacceleratorstorefront" />

    <extension name="yacceleratorcockpits" />


</extensions>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have access to the HMC and Storefront ?

Comment: HMC - Yes. Storefront- Not sure should that show up as a cockpit option in /mcc?

Comment: This generally happens when you have bad Url Patterns. You can read this thread for more information [Hybris Url Patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844084/hybris-cannot-find-cmssite-associated-with-current-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing somesteps I guess so.. pls try below quick steps and hope you will be good to go (working fine for me ..)

Step1: Go to the directory where you extracted hybris commerce suite zip file and go inside installer dir 
Example: let's say you you have hybris-commerce-suite-v6.0.zip and you extract to /Users/mark/hybris directory so let's go to the directory. 
cd /Users/mark/hybris/installer directory 
Step2: run below command to setup code for b2b accelerator ./install.sh -r b2b_acc 
++ more

COPIED From www.queshub.com 
[How to install B2B commerce accelerator in hybris6.](https://www.queshub.com/how-to-install-b2b-commerce-accelerator-in-hybris6)

Comment: What about b2c accelerator?

Comment: Change the steps  b2b_acc to b2c_acc or refer another post   http://www.ehybris.com/knowledgebase/12/how-to-install-b2c-commerce-accelerator-in-hybris6.html

Comment: This was helpful and got it up and running. Ran this recipe and then did ant initialize as well. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you probably haven't run an init.

Comment: How do you run an init? After starting the Hybris server?

Comment: https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Installation#Installation-initialize6.InitializehybrisCommerce